# asm.connect('mycomp1.y', 'mycomp2.x[5]') in OpenMDAO 1.x.x

Tags: openmdao

I'm new to OpenMDAO and I want to build an OpenMDAO model consisting of a windfarm (Group) which contains several wind turbines (Component). When all turbines are calculated some further calculations based on the results of all turbines (wind farm) shall be performed. For example: Each wind turbine component calulates its specific power output and in the end the total power shall be calculated as sum of the turbine specific power.

As it is mentioned in the conversion guide following functionality is not supported in new OpenMDAO:

```
asm.connect('windfarm.windturbine5.power', 'windfarm.eval.power[5]')
```

Is there any work around to achieve the same/similar result?

Thank you,
Jerome

---

**EDIT:**
Following example now works:

```
from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Component, Problem, Group


class Summer(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Summer, self).__init__()
        self.add_param('summand:x0', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('summand:x1', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('sum', shape=1)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        x0 = params['summand:x0']
        x1 = params['summand:x1']
        unknowns['sum'] = x0 + x1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    top = Problem()
    root = top.root = Group()
    root.add('wt0', IndepVarComp('power', 1000.0))
    root.add('wt1', IndepVarComp('power', 2000.0))
    root.add('eval', Summer())
    root.connect('wt0.power', 'eval.summand:x0')
    root.connect('wt1.power', 'eval.summand:x1')
    top.setup()
    top.run()
    print(top['eval.sum'])
```

**PS:** Is there an easy way to loop over a variable tree (e.g. params['summand'])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a separate input for each wind-far output. I suggest the following:

```
asm.connect('windfarm.windturbine0.power', 'windfarm.eval.power:0')
asm.connect('windfarm.windturbine1.power', 'windfarm.eval.power:1')
```

Comment: Hi Justin,
to name a variable of a variable tree only by number leads to an error: `NameError: : 'summand:0' is not a valid variable name.` But it works like in the example I added to my question. Thank you!